# permeation properties of concrete under surface treatment

Tags: civil-engineering, chemical-engineering

I wonder which permeation properties are critical in concrete with and without surface treatment (e.g sodium silicates-based solution) , is it air permeability,water permeability or absorption. If u were to measure two of them, what would u choose?